# JavaScript open a tab and track when it is closed

Tags: javascript

I open a tab from JavaScript and try to track when it is closed. But none of the events is fired. I only find examples with `onbeforeunload` referencing the current window, not other window-objects.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelector('#youtube-open').addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.yTT = window.open('https://youtube.com', '_blank');
        document.yTT.addEventListener('close', () => {
            console.log('onclose fired');
        });
        document.yTT.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
            console.log('onbeforeunload fired');
        });
        document.yTT.addEventListener('unload', () => {
            console.log('onunload fired');
        });
    });
});
```

There are no errors in the JS console or something. It just doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: Since your domain (probably) isn’t youtube.com, the same origin policy is violated and the window object you receive back from window.open is suitably secured.  See Return Value under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 0):

you can not access the other window instances of a browser. A way to bypass that is to use the local storage(which can be accessed from the events you listed above), to store some cross-tab data and a polling mechanism(in your main tab) to get the states.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to track when the window is closed just not that way.

Your `document.yTT` variable holds the `WindowProxy` object returned by `window.open()`. That object will not emit the events you are trying to listen to unfortunately. It will however hold a property that says if the window has been closed.

You can do this if you want to call a function when the window is closed :

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelector('#youtube-open').addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.yTT = window.open('https://youtube.com', '_blank');
        document.yTTInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (document.yTT.closed) {
                clearInterval(document.yTTInterval);
                executeSomeFunction();
            }
        }, 1); // or whatever interval works for you, the longer the less consuming
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! We've come up with that solution, too. Is there a way to get the real window object, not just the proxy?

Comment: I don't think so but why would you need the real window object ? This method works even for cross-domain, if you need to be able to attach a listener on it all you have to do is create an object with the WindowProxy and an EventEmitter